# How can I give input to my service without crushing its value with a global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, frontend

In the login service, the data in the request contains the user name and password. After going to the login service, role information is assigned to the data. When making a request to the generateToken service in the else section, it is still necessary to go with the user name and password, but the data variable is crushed and now contains the role information. How can I pass the username and password in the data variable to the generateToken service? I did as below with a global variable but I got timeout.

How can I use data variable in generateToken service with a global variable without timeout?

```
handleSubmit(data)
{
  localStorage.setItem("userEmail", data.email);
  this.props.dispatch(dispatchItem("USER_EMAIL", data.email));

  this.props.dispatch(
    login(
      data,
      (data) => {
        var userType = data.role;
        var roleExist = false;
        var roles = this.state.userType.split("|").filter((role) => role !== "");
        for (let index = 0; index < roles.length; index++) {
          if (userType.includes(roles[index])) {
            roleExist = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!roleExist) {
          var notification = {
            message: "You logged in from the wrong domain",
            isError: true,
          };
          this.props.dispatch(dispatchItem("NOTIFICATION", notification));
        } else {
          this.props.dispatch(
            generateToken(data, (data) => {
              var loginAccessToken = data.token;
              this.props.dispatch(dispatchItem("LOGIN_ACCESS_TOKEN", loginAccessToken));
            }),
          );
          this.changeActivePopup("otp");
        }
      },
      (data) => {},
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: what does `the data variable is crushed` mean? which variable exactly are you referring to ... `login(data, (data) => {` you do know you can call function arguments anything you like .... `login(data, (fred) => {` for example, then there is no confusion, or "crushing"

Comment: Why do you use the name `data` for at least 3 different things here?

Comment: @AKX - clearly OP is dealing with `data` so of course the variable is called `data` ... 

Comment: It's been named that way before and I don't want to spoil it either. There is user name and password information when going to the login service in the data request, then the role information is assigned as a result of the login response. I want to move the initial username and password to generateToken service. How can I do it?

Comment: this.props.dispatch(dispatchItem("USER_EMAIL", data.email)); 
var dataForGenerateToken = data;  
after saying genearateToken(dataForGenerateToken, (data) => {}
When you write it like this it's wrong, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, just rename the various nested `data`s to have better names.

- the outermost `data` is `loginData` probably
- the next `data` is `loginResponse` since it's in `login`'s callback
- the last `data` is `tokenResponse` since it's in `generateToken`'s callback

```
function handleSubmit(loginData)  {
  localStorage.setItem('userEmail', loginData.email);
  this.props.dispatch(dispatchItem('USER_EMAIL', loginData.email));

  this.props.dispatch(
    login(
      loginData,
      (loginResponse) => {
        var userType = loginResponse.role;
        var roleExist = false;
        var roles = this.state.userType.split('|').filter((role) => role !== '');
        for (let index = 0; index < roles.length; index++) {
          if (userType.includes(roles[index])) {
            roleExist = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!roleExist) {
          var notification = {
            message: 'You logged in from the wrong domain',
            isError: true,
          };
          this.props.dispatch(dispatchItem('NOTIFICATION', notification));
        } else {
          this.props.dispatch(
            generateToken(loginResponse, (tokenResponse) => {
              var loginAccessToken = tokenResponse.token;
              this.props.dispatch(dispatchItem('LOGIN_ACCESS_TOKEN', loginAccessToken));
            }),
          );
          this.changeActivePopup('otp');
        }
      },
      () => {},
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Consider a page logged in with a username and password. With these requests, the login service is accessed and after certain checks are passed the login service returns the role information. Then in order to send otp/token it is necessary to go to the genareteToken service. The generateToken service also asks for username and password as parameters. But since the username and password information is lost in the response part of the login service and the role information is replaced a bad request is returned from the generateToken service. generateToken service the same request as login service

Comment: When I change it as you said I get timeout from the login service. Do I need to do anything different in addition?

Comment: All I did in this example is mechanically change the variable names using PyCharm's Rename functionality. There are no functional changes, so there's no reason you would suddenly get a timeout.